# Printing neutron ports

Tags: python, django, openstack

When I do this: `neutron.list_ports()`

It gives me :

> {'ports': [{u'status': u'DOWN', u'name': u'', u'allowed_address_pairs': [], u'admin_state_up': True, u'network_id': u'-xxxx-84f2-e881c29879e2', u'dns_name': u'', xxxx': [], u'dns_assignment': [{u'hostname': u'host-134-xxxxx-xxx', u'ip_address': u'134.158.xx.xx', u'fqdn': u'host-134-158-75-xxx ... }

I only want to display the `u'ip_address'` field.

I hope you can help me :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there could be multiple ports but if you just need the first ip you should be able to do:

```
neutron.list_ports()["ports"][0]["dns_assignment"][0]["ip_addess"]
```

this will return the first ip you should probably check if any of this is null first though

Comment: Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 'ip_addess'

Comment: Sorry try `neutron.list_ports()["ports"][0]["dns_assignment"][0]["ip_addess"] `

Comment: the same error, I did this :  context = {
                        "info":neutron.list_ports()["ports"][0]["dns_assignment"][0]["ip_addess"]
                }

        return render(request, "auth/authSuccess.html", context)

Comment: what is the result if you do `neutron.list_ports()["ports"][0]["dns_assignment"][0]`

Comment: It works, but when I try to display many IP's in the same time , it gives me an another error : list indices must be integers, not str.

Comment: May I have your mail Brian Giggle, I have plenty of other questions :)

Comment: Sorry, I would like to help more but I don't really want to give out me email here